# Creating IP address range in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ip, ipv4

Suppose we have a list of IP addresses/blocks in a text file:

```
123.123.0.0
111.111.111.0
101.101.0.111
```

now I want to print out every possible IP address possible. For example for the first item in the list above:

```
123.123.0.0
123.123.0.1
123.123.0.2
123.123.0.3
[...]
123.123.0.255
123.123.1.1
123.123.1.2
[...]
123.123.255.255
```

I don't need help on reading and writing the files and etc. Just can't think of how I could print out every possible IP address in that block/range. Is it possible do a block and have it replace 0 with x and keep |x|, and print x between 1-255?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
require 'ipaddr'
puts IPAddr.new("123.123.0.0/16").to_range.to_a
```

If you absolutely have to use the ambiguous "IP defines range" data in the question,

```
require 'ipaddr'
STDIN.read.each_line do |line|
    num_zeroes = line[/(\.0)*$/].length / 2
    ip_range_string = "#{line.chomp}/#{32 - num_zeroes * 8}"
    puts IPAddr.new(ip_range_string).to_range.to_a
end
```